# Android: Upon Rotation, Current Fragment Disappears (How to Save State)

Tags: android, android-fragments, rotation, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

I've tried searching here and on Google and just cannot figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So my application consists of a `MainActivity` and multiple `Fragment`s, and it utilizes a `NavigationDrawer`. The drawer has been implemented just as it is in the [Android documentation for NavDrawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) (using the Support Library v4). Clicking on one of the several `ListView` Items on the left drawer loads a `Fragment` like below (this code is in `MainActivity`):

```
Fragment fragment = MyAmmunitionFragment.newInstance();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, MyAmmunitionFragment.Tag)
               .addToBackStack(Tag)
               .commit();

mLvLeftDrawer.setItemChecked(position, true);

setTitle(getString(R.string.my_ammunition));

mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLvLeftDrawer);
```

The problem I'm having is when I rotate the screen. Say one of my Fragments is loaded, like the one above. If the screen is rotated, the current `Fragment` disappears and my "homescreen" `Fragment` is displayed. By the way, when the app loads a "homescreen" `Fragment` is loaded by the `Activity`, as below:

```
private void populateMainSummaryFragment(int position, boolean addToBackStack) {
    Log.v(Tag, "populateMainSummaryFragment()");

    Fragment fragment = MainSummaryFragment.newInstance();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                                             .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);

    if (addToBackStack) {
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(Tag);
    }

    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    mLvLeftDrawer.setItemChecked(position, true);

    //setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLvLeftDrawer);
}
```

I have been able to save any text inputted by the user by overriding `onSaveInstanceState()` in the `Fragment` and storing the data in `SharedPreferences`, then loading from the preferences in the `Fragment`'s `onResume()` method.

My question is: **How do I save the current `Fragment` itself when the screen rotates (NOT just the data the user may have inputted)?**

Currently, I decided to save the current Fragment's tag in SharedPrefs, and then in the MainActivity's "onResume()" method read from SharedPrefs and load the Fragment using the same code as above. It's not working for some reason, and to me, it feels like a hacky/crappy solution. But, if that's what's gotta be done, so be it. It ain't working though, at the moment.

If I can ask a second question, how can I save user inputted data when the screen rotates, and NOT when the user merely navigates to another `Fragment`? Right now, the user inputted data is saved no matter if the screen is rotated or the Fragment navigated away from. I assume it's just logic and not some specific method call(s), but I'm not seeing the solution.

Thanks a ton for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the name of the current `Fragment` class in the `Activity`'s `onSaveInstanceState()`. In the `Activity`'s `onCreate()`,

```
if(savedInstanceState != null){

    /* get the name of the Fragment class that was previously saved
     * and load that Fragment, instead of loading HomeFragment. */

}
```

Now, to check whether the state change *is* due to rotation, use the following:

Create a class member

```
private int myOrientation;
```

In your `onCreate()`, use

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
myOrientation = display.getOrientation();
```

Afterwards, override the method `onConfigurationChanged()`, and here you can check if the orientation has actually changed or not:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    if(newConfig.orientation != myOrientation){
        // perform rotation-specific tasks
    }
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Try this. This will work.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick answer. So I guess I was on the right track by storing the Fragment's Tag (name) and then loading selectively based upon that. Hmmm. Just gotta figure out why that ain't workin.

As for the screen rotation detection code, thanks man! I will try it out.

Comment: So I finally got the saving and restoration of the current (last) Fragment to work. Basically, I save the Fragment's data and name (each Fragment has a public static "Tag" variable with its name) in SharedPreferences, in the Fragment's "onSaveInstanceState()" method. Then, in the MainActivity's "oncreate()" method, I read from SharedPrefs and check the current Fragment's name. Based upon the name, I load the respective Fragment with the code I had in my original question. The logic is split into separate methods but that is how I did it. I haven't done the rotation logic yet.

Comment: For some reason, I'm unable to scroll down on the Fragment after it's rotated. I will have to look into that. Any suggestions, anyone?

Comment: Just in case add this line to the manifest if don't have android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" for the onConfigurationChanged to be call